# CCleaner free equivalent on OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, open-source

Do you know a free (as in freedom) CCleaner equivalent which works on Mac OS X Mavericks?

I've searched but found nothing.

Comment: What exact features of CCleaner are you looking for in an OS X equivalent? For instance, CCleaner's registry cleaner has no direct equivalent since there's no registry in OS X.

Comment: The cleaning option. I want to install a new OS on my Mac.

Comment: If you want to install a new OS, why clean the old one? Are you going to restore a TM backup to the new install? If so, many caches etc are cleaned anyway.

Comment: i clean the old for have space on my hard drive. i install trisquel gnu/linux

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to re-partition to install another O/S then a cleaner won't do much, it really depends on how much room you need to recover for your partition.

That said there are a number of cleaners out there. I have always used the free Onyx. I usually get it off of MacUpdate. Note that the latest version is always for the latest O/S if you don't have Mavericks look on the developer's website for earlier versions.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx

Oddly enough CCCleaner is available for the Mac, and while I have used the PC version quite a bit I have never used it on the Mac, preferring to stick with the utility I know. So I can't speak to how good a job CCCleaner does on the Mac.

MacUpdate is a great place to look for software, pretty much everything you are looking for here can be found there.

Comment: OnyX is proprietary. I search a free equivalent.

Comment: Onyx is free, always has been. If you mean free as in open source I am not aware of anything that does this that is also open source